# Values of some html tags rendered as question marks with boxes around them

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

- Programming Language: Python 3.8
- Package: bs4
- Browser: Google Chrome

**Problem**

I am trying to scrape a restaurant's review score from a review website (da zhong dian ping - essentially China's version of yelp).

I am new to web scraping and starting with bs4. I am able to get most of the information I want such as the review title and review comment, however, when I try to get the score (for example, Service: 4.5) the numbers are rendered as a question mark inside of a box using the Google Inspect tool in Chrome.

Is this an issue with my computer, Chrome, bs4, or is it just the website (maybe they don't want the review score scraped)?

I apologize if some of the terms used to describe my problem are wrong or unclear, my vocabulary related to html and web scraping is still quite low so I've had a hard time finding any good answers through online searches.

Here's a screen snip: [image]

Comment: can you send the page link

Comment: http://www.dianping.com/shop/H4K9r25vw2LQTV3U

Comment: Ok, thanks @QHarr. I wasn't sure which specific website/forum to ask this question on.